# Converting a Bash function to compute n! to C?

Tags: c, bash, loops, factorial

I am attempting to re-write this bash function in C, but the a little unsure of how to convert this function into a C loop.

Here I have variables set. This I already have

```
n=10
r=4
```

This is where I get a little lost on how to re-write this. This seems to be calling the function with its own function and I pretty sure C will not do that (safely at least ) Also it does not need to be a function at all, I just need to plug in the same variables and have it come out with the same result.

```
factorial() {
if (($1)); then
    echo $(($1 * $(factorial $(($1-1)))))
else
    echo 1
fi
}
```

The last bit, is what would be the best way to express the code below in C? Would the bracketing in bash carry over?

```
result=$(($(factorial $n)/($(factorial $r)*$(factorial $(($n-$r))))))
```

Comment: factorial works in the bounds of standard integer types for so few input integers, that I'd just do a lookup table, instead of calculating the loop. You'll have to check the user input to be within bounds anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's totally legal for C functions to call themselves - this is called *[recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)*.  In C, it would look like this:

```
int factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

You could also write this directly as a loop:

```
int factorial(int n) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
 int factorial(int i)
 {
    if(i)
       return factorial(i - 1) * i;
    return 1;
 }

 int main()
 {
     printf("%d", factorial(5));
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `int main()`?  Or is `void main()` legal C?

Answer (score 0):

As it involves a lot less function call overhead I'd prefer the non_recursive version, nevertheless both of them shoud work.
I don't know how bash handles huge numbers, unfortunately in C long double is the maximum range you can get without using external libraries.

```
long double recursive (int n) {
  if (n <= 1)
    return 1.0;
  else return (n * recursive (n-1));
}

long double non_recursive (int n) {
  long double value = 1.0;

  while (n > 1)
    value *= n--;

  return value;
}
```

To answer your second question, I'd recommend the following mathematical transformation prior to the calculation, to spare unnecessary computational overhead:

```
  n!               (M+1) * (M+2) * ... * n
-----------    =   ------------------------  
r! * (n-r)!             (n-m) !

                  with M = max (r, n-r), m = min (r, n-r);
```

Given this transformation the corresponding C code would look like this:

```
long double over (int n, int r) {

  int M;
  int m;

  if  (r > n-r) {
    M = r+1;
    m = n-r;
  }
  else {
    M = n-r + 1;
    m = r;
  }

  long double value = 1.0;

  while (M <= n)
    value *= M++;

  while (m > 1)
    value /= m--;

  return value;
}
```